# Heroku App not comnpatible with buildpack

Tags: heroku

I am trying to add the buildpack:https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play to my heroku app , I manually added it using heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play but when I did git push heroku master I got the following error...[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNLp1.png)

Comment: *"The buildpack will detect your app as using the Play! framework if it has an application.conf in a conf directory."* - does that apply to you? Give a [mre].

Comment: No I dont think I have any files related to the Play framework, what files do I need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play

> Note: This buildpack only applies to Play 1.2.x and 1.3.x apps. Play
>   2.x apps are handled by the Scala buildpack
>
> Play 1.x support is deprecated and ending on June 1, 2017. Please see
>   the getting started documentation for Play 2.x.

heroku-buildpack-play is deprecated. Use a different solution (e.g. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala). Support of it ended almost 3 years ago.

Comment: You mean its outdated and I should replace it with the one you suggested?

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala#how-it-works Please invest the time and read it. I haven't worked with those buildpacks yet but the documentation about it is pretty thorough. Question should be closed since your original question is answered. If you have further questions create a new one and put more effort into asking good questions.